# Delete folder from svn having the special character sign & ampersand

Tags: bash, svn, terminal

I m trying to delete or remove the svn folder which has the speacial character & sign in between the folder name and unfortunately its not being found in the working copy in xcode and all the time my build gets failed.
When trying to delete the Folder using terminal it always returns the error as
"svn delete --force PlayDate/Model/Cell\ Classes/Places&FavoritesCell
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXkrx.jpg) 43050
-bash: FavoritesCell: command not found"

Attaching up the screenshot for the same to get the clear idea
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXkrx.jpg
Thanks in Advance for the help

Answer (score 1):

Because `&` is a special/reserved character for the shell (similar to space), you need to escape it by either:

- Preceding it with a backslash (`svn delete --force PlayDate/Model/Cell\ Classes/Places\&FavoritesCell`)
- Wrap the whole path in single quotes (`'svn delete --force PlayDate/Model/Cell\ Classes/Places&FavoritesCell'`)

See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/69147

A third option would be to delete the item from the repository by URL instead. To do that, you'd need to URLEncode the spaces and ampersand(s) in the name, or wrap the URL in single quotes as above. Then run `svn update` to sync that change to your working copy and delete the now-"orphaned" file locally via Finder or normal bash commands.

Comment: Thanks for the help can't upvote ur answer due to low reputation.Worked like a charm was smashing up with this since last 2 hrs :)